# Trouble accessing information on an external hard drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I have a StoreJet 500GB external hard drive with 100's of movie files. I have a Windows operating system. I am not able to copy all the files to my internal hard drive:
- unless I am in Safe Mode
- and even then it cannot "read" all files - even though you can see them in Explorer...

*I have had to resort to Safe Mode as it won't read the disk otherwise.
I have run the Scan Disk utility and repaired bad sectors, without success.*

Comment: >> I am not able to copy all the files to my internal hard drive - Why not? What happens when you try?  What error messages do you get?

Comment: Does it work fine on another system?

Comment: @Seth - No, it is inaccessible from a Mac

Comment: If you can't access it from either system it might just be a damaged drive. Do you hear any strange noises when it tries to access any data? You could try to use something like `tree /F /A > fileondrive.txt` to get a list of files on the drive and copy all the data you can copy. So you would have an idea of what you lost. What do you mean it won't read the disk unless you're in safe mode? In addition look at the other comment and try to answer those questions as well.

Comment: I agree with @seth. It looks like you might be dealing with a failed drive. Please, try to backup all your important files from the external HDD while in Safe Mode. This is how you will avoid the data loss. After making a duplicate of the files, run an HDD diagnostic tool to determine the health and SMART status of the drive. I'd also suggest you try using a different USB cable to see if it would improve the connection somehow. Keep us posted with the troubleshooting & details. Good luck!

Comment: @mcalex - The error reads: 
Can't read from source field or disk

Comment: @SuperSoph_WD - I will try the different USB just now... Crazy thing is, I was able to access some files in normal operating mode now.... A couple of confusing things happening with this one as it is not **consistently** giving the same errors...

Comment: @infinitquest since you are able to access some of the files now, copy them elsewhere immediately. It's possible that a failed connection with the external drive can cause miscommunication with the computer. I hope you avoid the data loss. After backing up, I'd again advise you to test the external hard drive's health and SMART status using a diagnostic tool. Keep us posted with the results.

Comment: Possible hard disk failure. Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive's SMART status in Windows 7?](//superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](//superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.